# Is there a better way to update database by index instead of by its column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Above is a screenshot of my database,

- Each row represents a task
- *ReviewedTimes* represents how many times a task is reviewed, it can be set to up to 9.
- *FirstReview, SecondReview ... TenthReview* represent a `DateTime` that this given task is reviewed.

My current approach is:

1. For a given task, read its *ReviewedTimes* column value, `N`
2. With a few blocks of `if-else` (or `switch`) statements, update a *(N+1)thReview* column.

For example, for a given task, its *ReviewedTimes* column reads 3, I will update *FourthReview* column with a new `DateTime` value.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same goal? I am thinking:

- If I can somehow Enumerate *FirstReview*, *SecondReview* ... *TenthReview* as 1, 2 ... 10
- Based on *ReviewedTimes* value, *N*, I can update column *N + 1* respectively.

Comment: @marc_s, thanks. I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @YuZhang How about changing your database design to have a table called review, then insert a record in it when ever a task is reviewed with the task primary key as foreign key and a column for timestamp, Task has one to many relationship with review

Comment: @RyanWilson, thank you for this suggestion, I will definitely look into it.

Comment: @YuZhang You're welcome. Sorry I didn't really answer your question.

Comment: @RyanWilson, no, you provided a different approach. I never thought of it. It is definitely a solution.

Comment: The book, Database Design for Mere Mortals might give you some other good ideas.

Comment: @YuZhang it would just be easier to restrict or expand the number of reviews that way, just think if you wanted to allow 15 reviews per task, then you would have to add 5 new columns to your current table structure.

Comment: Hey @RyanWilson I think that table refactor applies as an answer. I will gladly upvote it. If you do, provide the script the OP will need to do the changes and also how the solution will it look like with your design.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Ok. I'll post my suggestion as you asked in the form of an answer, might take me a few minutes.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Done sir, if my answer is lacking in anyway, please let me know what I missed and I will add to it.

Comment: Not clear to me.  Please show desired result  and existing TSQL.  Post input data in text.

Comment: @YuZhang Definitely do what Ryan suggested.  This way, a book can have 0 review, or 1000 reviews, not restricted to only 10 reviews.

Comment: @DanBracuk, just found the book. Added to my read list. Cheers for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I suggested in my above comment, Tasks has a one-to-many relationship with Reviews, to do what I suggested in SQL Server, you'll need to first drop all the Review Columns from the Task Table:

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tasks]
    DROP COLUMN [FirstReview], DROP COLUMN [SecondReview], etc...
```

Then Create a new table called Review which has a foreign key to the primary key of Task table, this is assuming you have an Identity column in Tasks called TaskId:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reviews] ([ReviewId] INT NOT NULL Identity(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, [TaskId] INT NOT NULL References [dbo].[Tasks]([TaskId]), [TimeStamp] DateTime NOT NULL)
```

Now when someone goes to review a task item, you would first check to see if the review limit has been reached by using COUNT() on the Review Table for a given Task ID, if it has not been reached, insert a new record of the task review in Review table with the Task Id as TaskID column value and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to return the datetime of Review. If you are tracking the person who reviewed the task, you would then add another column to Review with a foreign key to the user id, but that is just another suggestion.

Comment: Fantastic! Cheers.